# GLSL trouble with sine curve

Tags: three.js, glsl, trigonometry, vertex-shader

I am trying to alter vertex positions in a vertex shader to form a sine curve along a shape's surface.

As seen in the middle of the page [here](https://thebookofshaders.com/05/), a sine wave moving vertically along the z axis could be generated with the simple pattern `z = sin(u_time + y);`. For every new Y pos, increment the Z pos inward/outward, forming a sine path.

For some reason the outcome is different in my vertex shader. The surface of the shape is changing, but it always stays flat, instead of conforming to a sine curve. See the vertex shader in the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/35w7fsqo/1/ , namely the line

```
p.z += sin((time + position.y) / duration) * amplitude;
```

Here's a diagram showing what I mean:
[image]

What do I need to do to get this surface to conform to a sine curve?

Comment: I encountered few times that math functions used in Vertex or Geometry shaders  (goniometrics included) sometimes does not behave as should (leading to wrong results) while in Fragment shader they are always as they should...

Answer (score 1):

The BoxGeometry which this shader was running on didn't have enough vertices along the face, it only had one at each corner. I added more `heightSegments` in the [constructor](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry) like so `var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200, 1, 10, 1);` and now sine curves are visible: https://jsfiddle.net/35w7fsqo/2/